# PostMessage to Open Outlook Reply Window?

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I want to send keys to a background window.
In this case, outlook.
 I have this code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        string processName = "outlook";
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process P in processList)
        {
            if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
            {
                IntPtr edit = P.MainWindowHandle;
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.LControlKey), IntPtr.Zero);
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.R), IntPtr.Zero);
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(Keys.R), IntPtr.Zero);
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(Keys.LControlKey), IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }                         
    }
```

What is wrong with this? It is supposed to open a reply window in outlook, but it doesn't.
Also, please don't answer with something outlook specific related as I want to use this method to do it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Thanks for that! Also, to whoever fixed it aswell.